# Developer Mode option is the settings menu is grayed out in Hololens 2

Tags: hololens

I just received Hololens2 from my org and I am not able to turn on the developer option in the settings menu. Is there any way to get around in this?

Best,
Samvid

Comment: You might want to look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/using-visual-studio#hololens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your device is owned by an organization, and Developer unlock option has been disabled. You need to contact the IT of your organization to specify developer unlock is allowed by setting ApplicationManagement policy: [ApplicationManagement/AllowDeveloperUnlock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/client-management/mdm/policy-csp-applicationmanagement#applicationmanagement-allowdeveloperunlock)